# combo box checked items to single string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, combobox, telerik

Here is my code ,

```
string _towns = String.Join(",", 
(usercontrol.FindControl("comboTown") as RadComboBox).CheckedItems);
```

'comboTown' has the values

```
Town1
Town2
Town3
Town4
```

If I checked `Town2` and `Town3` , I want to get the single string likes `Town2,Town3` separated by comma . But my code return `Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem,Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem` . How can I get only the value of checked items ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to access property `Text` of `RadComboBoxItem`

```
var selectedTowns = (usercontrol.FindControl("comboTown") as RadComboBox)
                                .Items.Where(i => i.Checked)
                                .Select(i => i.Text)
                                .ToArray();

string _towns = String.Join(",", selectedTowns);
```

Comment: It's return `FitInInput` !

Comment: Problem lies somewhere else then, my LONG guess is that you rebinded control on post back, but to be sure can you debug and see what items there are in `comboTown`?

Answer (score 2):

```
string _towns = String.Join(",",(usercontrol.FindControl("comboTown") as RadComboBox).Items
   .Where(i => i.Checked)
   .Select(i => i.Text).ToList());
```

OR

```
string _towns = String.Join(",",(usercontrol.FindControl("comboTown") as RadComboBox).CheckedItems).Select(i => i.Text).ToList());
```

Comment: It's return `FitInInput` !

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
//Register Combo Selected Index Changed Event
Combo_OnSelectedIndexChange(abc,abc) {
{
str.append(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text+",");
}
```